# SQL Display record of non equal to

Tags: sql

We have a single table with 2 columns, name & check_in_date

Every employee will check-in daily for every working day.
But if I want to find out on a specific day, who did not check in, how do I go about it?

```
select name from table
where check_in_date <> '2021-06-17'
```

The above will not work for me as it will display records outside of 2021-06-17.
I wanted to see only the names that did not check in on that date.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need a table of employees.  Then you would use `not exists`:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where not exists (select 1
                  from checkins ci
                  where ci.name = e.name and ci.date = ?
                 );
```

The `?` is a placeholder for your date.

If you don't have a separate table, you can use aggregation instead:

```
select name
from checkins
group by name
having sum(case when ci.date = ? then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, the aggregation method works well in my scenario.